# How to check if an Image has geo-info on flickr - python

Tags: python, flickr

Here is my code so far:

```
import flickrapi
import osmapi
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import overpy
import requests
import xmltodict
from time import sleep

api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
secret_api_key = "xxxxxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

def obtainImages3():

    group_list = flickr.groups.search (api_key=api_key, text = 'Paris', per_page = 10)

    for group in group_list[0]:

        group_images = flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos (api_key=api_key, group_id = group.attrib['nsid'], extras = 'geo, tags, url_s')

        for image in group_images[0]:

            url = str(image.attrib['url_s'])
            tags = (image.attrib['tags']).encode('utf-8')

            #ONLY RUN THIS CODE IF IMAGE HAS GEO INFO

                photo_location = flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=image.attrib['id'])
                lat = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['latitude'])
                lon = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['longitude'])

                geolocator = Nominatim()
                location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(lat, lon))
                dict = location.raw
                osmid = dict.get('osm_id', 'default_value_if_null_here')
                osmtype = dict.get('osm_type', 'default_value_if_null_here')
                osmaddress = dict.get('display_name', 'default_value_if_null_here')
                sleep(1)

                if(osmtype == 'node'):
                    node_info = requests.get("http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/"+ osmid)
                    #print node_info.content
                    d = xmltodict.parse(node_info.content)
                    amenity_tags = [tag for tag in d['osm']['node']['tag'] if tag['@k'] == 'amenity']
                    amenity_name = [tag for tag in d['osm']['node']['tag'] if tag['@k'] == 'name']

                    if len(amenity_tags) != 0:
                        amenity_type = amenity_tags[0]['@v']
                        amenity_type_name = amenity_name[0]['@v']
                        print amenity_type
                        print amenity_type_name
                        print url

obtainImages3()
```

I want to run the code following the comment if and only if geo-info is available on the image obtained. In my group_images api call, I am asking for geo info to be returned if it it present.

I have tried for example if `image.attrib['geo'] != None`, and have tried a try/ exception block but all are returning errors, especially key errors.

Can anyone suggest an easy way to figure out if the image has geo info, so that the code below the comment will only run if it is available?

Comment: have you looked at the available keys for attrib? If you are getting key errors then geo probably isn't the right key, or it is the right key but it is only in there if it has geo information.

Comment: @SirParselot It actually would be something like image.attrib['latitude'] but its keeps telling me no location info available. I only want the program to continue if location info available

Comment: try something like `if 'latitude' in image.attrib`. My guess is that it only creates the key latitude if it exists in the picture. You could also try printing the value in `image.attrib['latitude']`.